# How to plot 3D bar chart in Matplotlib with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

So I have a CSV with dataframe which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUaBE.jpg)

Here is the CSV [file](https://userscloud.com/x3baw7f7e8de)

Time Start is when the person entered the room, Time end is when the person left.
The Duration for how many minutes they stayed in the Room is given in Duration(min) whereas the Room is in room column. The person is named in person column.

I want to create a 3D Chart as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsTF.jpg).
Which plots according to how many time duration a person stayed in which room. Like suppose on 1:00 person 'A' entered the room S2 and he left on 3:00 so the 3D chart will have a bar from that timeline.

Till Now, What I tried is create a new dataframe with the start and end times merged uniquely and trying to plot it on Y axis. But it's now working.

I am new to matplotlib, I would appreciate if someone could help me on how to create this chart

Here is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas
import os
 
df = pandas.read_csv("table1_short.csv")
 
timeline = []
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    curr = df.iloc[i]
    start_t, end_t = (curr['Time Start'], curr['Time End'])
    start_obj = datetime.strptime(start_t[:start_t.index(".")], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end_obj   = datetime.strptime(end_t[:end_t.index(".")], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    timeline.append(start_obj)
    timeline.append(end_obj)
    
    
new_df = pandas.DataFrame()
new_df['date obj'] = list(tuple(timeline))
 
 
x =  df['Person'] # x coordinates of each bar
y =  new_df['date obj'] # y coordinates of each bar
z =  df['Room']  # z coordinates of each bar
dx = [0.5 for item in list(range(0, len(df)))]  # Width of each bar
dy = [0.5 for item in list(range(0, len(df)))]  # Depth of each bar
dz = df['Duration(min)']        # Height of each bar
 
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax12 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 
ax12.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you say that it's now working, what is happening? Are you encountering an error or are you getting an unexpected output? The more detailed information you provide about what you have tried and what exactly is going wrong, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @JeffreySwan I mean I get erros like ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape, Ufunc Error and other errors I am not much aware of. I am fairly new to matplotlib and need help on how it should be done.